# Passing the name of a C++ function through two nested functions

Tags: c++

I am very new to C++, and I'm pretty stuck on this problem I'm currently working on.

Essentially, I have three functions that I'm working with. The goal is to pass the name of a function as an argument to a primary function. The primary function then passes that name of a function to a secondary function. Inside of the secondary function, the function whose name was being passed is finally called. A rough of idea of what the code looks like is included below and I can't get it to work since when it is called in sub_fun it expects it to be subfun(...).

```
double my_function(double& x, const double& y){
    ...
}

int sub_fun(std::function<double(double&, const double&)> my_function){
    ...
    my_function(arg1, arg2);
    ...
}

int big_fun(std::function<double(double&, const double&)> my_function){
    ...
    sub_fun(my_function, ...);
    ...
}

int main() {
    big_fun(my_function)
}
```

I'm still learning about pointers/references, so I'm pretty sure I might be making a mistake. If I didn't explain it well enough please let me know, and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Sorry, edited the original.

Comment: what does this mean: "when it is called in sub_fun it expects it to be subfun(...)."

Comment: @stoa You said you can't get it to work since when it is called in sub_fun it expects it to be subfun(...). What do you mean? Does it print an error message? Or does it have some other result?

Comment: please create a [mcve] and show the compiler error you get. Because it would - except the warnings that should be fixed - compiles without any errors that way: ([wandbox.org](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rKHKjk28tDL0Fjw7)).

Comment: I get the error "no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::__1::function<double (double &, const double &)>'" because I think it expects it to have arguments.

Comment: It might help if you changed the argument `my_function` in big_fun and sub_fun to some other name -- just so you don't confuse it with the actual `my_function ` function

Comment: This code structure you showed so far is OK. To get help with errors you will need to actually post the real code that is getting the errors.

Comment: `sub_fun(my_function, ...);` is a problem. `sub_fun` expects 1 argument. You can't call it with more arguments. Do you want a variadic function / template with argument forwarding? If you change `sub_fun(my_function, ...);` to `sub_fun(my_function);` it works: https://wandbox.org/permlink/M4AfS1d7WdMpr5Al

Comment: Thank you everyone, I appreciate your help. @ThomasSablik, I am compiling this code to be used into R, and I think it is an issue with the way it's being compiled. So my code works, the compiler is just angry about something else...I'll keep digging!

Answer (score 1):

`sub_fun(my_function, ...);` is a problem. `sub_fun` expects 1 argument. You can't call it with more arguments. If you change `sub_fun(my_function, ...);` to `sub_fun(my_function);` it works:

```
#include <functional>

double my_function(double& x, const double& y){
    return x + y;
}

int sub_fun(std::function<double(double&, const double&)> my_function){
    double arg1 = 0, arg2 = 0;
    my_function(arg1, arg2);
    return 0;
}

int big_fun(std::function<double(double&, const double&)> my_function){
    sub_fun(my_function);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    big_fun(my_function);
}
```

If you want to pass the arguments through `sub_fun` you can use a variadic template:

```
#include <functional>

double my_function(double& x, const double& y){
    return x + y;
}

template<typename ...Ts>
int sub_fun(std::function<double(double&, const double&)> my_function, Ts ...args){
    my_function(args...);
    return 0;
}

int big_fun(std::function<double(double&, const double&)> my_function){
    double arg1 = 0, arg2 = 0;
    sub_fun(my_function, arg1, arg2);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    big_fun(my_function);
}
```

You could also use a variadic function instead of the variadic template but variadic templates are more powerful and IMHO easier to use.